# How to put content inside td to be horizontal at center of cell?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Inside tag  I can have text or icon, I created this with template like

```
<td>
 <span style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">{{r['username']}}</span>
</td>
<td>
 <span style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">{% if r['nation'] == 1 %}
  <img src="../static/images/Flag_Native.png" />{% elif r['nation'] == 2 %}
  <img src="../static/images/Flag_American.png" />{% elif r['nation'] == 3 %}
  <img src="../static/images/Flag_Britain.png" />{% else %}
  <img src="../static/images/Flag_France.png"/>{% end %}
 </span>
</td>
<td>
 <span style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">{{r['score']}}
 </span>
</td>
```

I also tried without span only inside td like `<td align="center">` but it didn't work.

How to put content inside td to be horizontal at center of cell ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<td style='margin: 0 auto; align:center;'>
```

or wrap it in a div as such

```
<td><div style='margin: 0 auto; align:center; width: 100%;'><span style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">{{r['username']}}</span></div></td>
```

The div would probably be best because I think that the width property also needs to be set.